# How to reverse specific ranges of a vector at the same time in R?

Tags: r, vector, reverse

For example, I have the matrix `A`, which is the following:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1   -1   -1
 [9,]    1    1   -1   -1
[10,]    1    1   -1   -1
[11,]    1    1   -1   -1
[12,]    1   -1    1   -1
[13,]    1   -1    1   -1
[14,]    1   -1    1   -1
[15,]    1   -1    1   -1
[16,]    1   -1   -1    1
[17,]    1   -1   -1    1
[18,]    1   -1   -1    1
[19,]    1   -1   -1    1
```

Using the code:

```
Y=unique(A[,3:4])
YY=list()
q=0
for( i in 1:nrow(Y) )
{
a=which(apply(A, 1, function(x) identical(x[3:4], Y[i,])))
if( length(a)>1 )
{
q=q+1
YY[[q]]=a
}}
```

I obtain the ranges of columns 3 and 4 of matrix A, that have the same elememts.
That is, the list `Y` is:

```
YY
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11
[[3]]
[1] 12 13 14 15
[[4]]
[1] 16 17 18 19
```

So, let say I have the vector `x=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)`.
The desired reversion of `x`, due to list `YY`, is the following:
    `c(-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1)`.

The point is to success reversing of a vector for as many ranges as may I have at the same time.

NOTE THAT THE RANGES AND THE NUMBER OF THEM CAN CHANGE.

I tried to use `rev()` with `apply()`, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How will the ranges to be reversed be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
x[unlist(sapply(YY, rev))]
```

The dependence on `YY` is implemented here and the orders will vary accordingly whenever `YY` varies.